# Renaming model with migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an existing model 'micropost' and I found out that there is better name for the model to suit my application. What would be the better approach to rename 'micropost' model to 'story' model without affecting its indexes? I am working on Rails 5.0.0.rc1. The migration snippet is:

```
class CreateMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :microposts do |t|
     t.text :content
     t.references :user, index: true

     t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :microposts, [:user_id, :created_at]
 end
end
```

Comment: If you have the database locally then go and chnage all the names as per your need, Otherwise create one migration to rename the same thing.

Comment: @Bharatsoni Thank you for your prompt reply. Should I be using up and down methods? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 .Make migration to change the database table name from micropost to story.

```
class RenameOldTableToNewTable< ActiveRecord::Migration              
  def change   
    rename_table :old_table_name, :new_table_name   
  end  
end
```

2 .Change manually the Active Record model class into Story

Answer (score 0):

**Run command on console:**

> $ rails g migration RenameMicropostToStory

Edit migration file:

```
class RenameMicropostToStory < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    rename_table :microposts, :stories
  end

end
```

then,

> $ rake db:migrate